# Как обойти ошибку повторного включения заголовочных файлов

Tags: c++, линковка

Доброго времени суток.

**С чем имею дело:**
Есть три класса: Parent, ChildA, ChildB. Классы ChildA и ChildB напрямую наследуются от Parent. Каждый из этих классов объявлен в своем заголовочном файле (.h) и определен также в отдельном .cpp файле.

файл Parent.h

```
class Parent {
    //какие-то объявления
};
```

файл ChildA.h

```
#include "Parent.h"
class ChildA : public Parent {
    //какие-то объявления
};
```

файл ChildB.h

```
#include "Parent.h"
class ChildB : public Parent {
    //какие-то объявления
};
```

Классы ChildA и ChildB используются в файле main.cpp содержащем функцию main().

файл main.cpp

```
#include "ChildA.h"
#include "ChildB.h"

int main() {
    //какой-то код использующий классы ChildA и ChildB
    return 0;
}
```

понятно, что в процессе линковки возникнет ошибка повторного включения заголовочного файла Parent.h

**Интсрументы:** компилировал с помощью g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0, используя команду g++ main.cpp Parent.cpp ChildA.cpp ChildB.cpp -o main.exe.

**В чем проблема:** так вот - можно изменять только файл main.cpp. Я не знаю как в этом случае обойти эту ошибку. Причем способ не должен быть специфичным для какого-то определенного компилятора или платформы, т.к. переносимость кода крайне важна.

**Текст ошибки:** In file included from ChildB.h:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Parent.h:1:7: error: redefinition of 'class Parent'
 class Parent {
       ^~~~~~
In file included from ChildA.h:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
Parent.h:1:7: error: previous definition of 'class Parent'
 class Parent {
       ^~~~~~

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: В С++ многократное включение заголовочных файлов не является ошибкой. Ошибка из-за отсутствия header guard в `Parent.h`, вызывающего множественное определение класса `Parent`, не может происходить на этапе линковки. Ну а если изменять его нельзя - то делайте адаптеры в виде pimpl или еще как-нибудь чтобы в каждую единицу трансляции он включался только один раз.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки. Вы видимо, что-то путаете, включение заголовков присходит как предварительный этап компиляции, на этап ликовки никакие заголовоки влиять не могут.

Comment: Что мешает внести в Parent.h ***include guard*** (`#ifndef _PARENT_H_ \n #define _PARENT_H_ \n ... здесь текст вашего Parent.h  ... #endif`)?

Comment: Cerbo - я дополнил свой вопрос включив код ошибки.

Comment: VTT, спасибо за указание на header guard. Присутствуй он в Parent.h  - и проблемы бы не было. Но к сожалению изменять Parent.h нельзя. Думаю вопрос можно на этом закрыть. Хотя я не решил проблему, за то точно знаю как не стоит писать  заголовочные файлы библиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в заголовочном файле используются [include guard'ы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) или директива [`#pragma once`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once). Однако, если по какой-то причине нельзя изменить заголовочный файл, можно применить небольшой хак:

```
// Файл "ParentGuarded.h"

#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

#include "Parent.h"

#endif
```

Соответственно, в свои файлы включать ParentGuarded.h вместо Parent.h.

Comment: *можно изменять только файл main.cpp* Соответственно `#include "Parent.h"` в `ChildA.h` и `ChildB.h` никуда не денется.